# Copying Hundred of Thousands Files from Remote Directory to Another Remote Directory

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp, sftp

I have a remote directory (SSH enabled) on `11.11.11.11/:/path/from` (an Ubuntu machine) that has **millions** of tiny `.txt` small size files, doing like simple `ls` command or even opening the `/path/from/` directory using WinSCP is impossible because there are **millions**  of files.

My goal is to find few thousands files that have a specific name pattern **and** copy them to another remote location (e.g `22.22.22.22:/path/to`).

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
scp --exec=`find /path/from -name 'A*random*' -mtime +0 -mtime -10` user@22.22.22.22:/path/to
```

But it takes a long long time to do that, like I said the `/path/from/` directory contains literally millions of files.

Do you have suggestion to make it faster? Using `rsync`? How should I do it? And how can I limit the `find` result to a certain number, let's say `1000`, because I only know how to limit it using the last modified on date, `-mtime`.

Comment: Have you tried using the include and exclude in rsync? e.g,  rsync -nrv --include="*/" --include="A*random*" --exclude="*" /path/from/  (Note that the * is missing between A and random, it disappears when I save the comment!)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `find` in combination with `cpio` to create a stream from your many files on one machine and extract the files with `cpio` on the other machine.

```
ssh user@source "cd sourcedir && find ./ -xdev -name 'A*random*' -print | cpio -o -Bav -H crc" | ssh user@target "cd destinationdir && cpio -i -vumd"
```

This (untested) solution is based on https://www.netroby.com/view/3602 . There you will find some explanation of the arguments for `find` and `cpio` .

Comment: how to limit into let say 1000 first files found using `find`?

Comment: @xcode: Why do you want to do this? Do you want to continue with the next 1000 files later? You could use something like `find ./ -xdev -name 'A*random*' -print | head -1000`... but if you want to continue later I suggest to save `find`'s output to a file first, then use `split` (or `head` and `tail`) and a loop. The result of repeated `find` calls may be inconsistent if files are created or removed in between.

Comment: this doesn't work it always give me `cpio: Too many arguments`
`cpio: premature end of archive` errors

Comment: @xcode I fixed a typo. The first `cpio` command should be `cpio -o -Bav -H crc` (not ... `-o Bav` ...)

Answer (score 0):

### Try `locate`

It seems `find` is too slow for this application.

- There is a faster tool to find files, **`locate`**. It uses a database, that must be updated for `locate` to find the newest files.
- **`updatedb`** creates or updates a database used by `locate`. If the database already exists, its  data is reused to avoid rereading directories that have not changed.

  This update process is very fast compared to `find` and when the database is updated, `locate` will find all files (and it is much faster than `find`).

### Usage

- *Create* and next times *update* the database

  ```
  sudo updatedb
  ```
- *Find* the relevant files. `locate` provides several useful options but not a lot of options like `find`. You might be able to design a **useful pattern** for your purpose.

  I suggest two command lines, that you may modify, and later combine with `scp` or `rsync`.

  You can limit the number of files with `--limit`

  If you search only in `/path/from/` and not in sub-directories

  ```
  locate --regex --limit 1000 '/path/from/A.*random.*'
  ```

  If you search not in `/path/from/` itself but in its sub-directories

  ```
  locate --regex --limit 1000 '/path/from/.*/A.*random.*'
  ```

  See `man locate` for more details.

### General comments

- Maybe you should modify how these files are written and stored, for example with several sub-directories, so that there are not too many files in each directory, for example one sub-directory for each date (`2019-02-12`, `2019-02-13` ...),

  or even better, like many photo managers are storing picture files,

  - one level of subdirectories for each year
  - the next level of subdirectories for each month of the year
  - the final level of subdirectories for each day of the month, where the files are stored.
- Maybe you can also remove some files (for example when they are getting too old).

Answer (score 0):

1. tar, zip, or compress everything under the folder into one `source.tar` file; can quickly do via `tar -cf /sourcedirectory`; this will be however large containing all 100,000+ files now in one file.
2. transfer this one file however you like
3. once at the destination, `tar -xf source.tar` or unzip/uncompress appropriately back to the original folder structure containing 100,000+ files.